# How do I locate the source of an annoying periodic 'ding' sound produced by Chrome on MacOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, audio, system-sounds

How do I locate the source of an extremely irritating periodic 'ding' sound?

I've used SoundSource with its per-app volume controls to identify Chrome as the source, but despite disabling extensions one by one I'm still getting it, roughly every minute or two. Its driving me batty!

Here's a recording of the ding:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RxYZnJe0KuC6wWupKv82pUKP4o4nWVFN/view?usp=sharing

- I tried using an "identify sound source" chrome extension, but the ding apparently happens too fast.
- Not seeing a playing sound icon appear on any tabs

It almost seems like Chrome itself is generating the ding, but the sound's quality doesn't seem high enough to be a major vendor's WAV. It almost feels like a Windows 95 era sound.

Comment: idk how to track it down, but it sounds like some kind of 'you have mail' type sound, RSS feed or open conversation etc as the message updates.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable all your chrome extensions and see if you still hear it.

Paste this in your browser address bar:

chrome://extensions/

I don't think any versions of chrome ship with that sound; it's not Chrome.